# How to re-enable the `enable` command?

Tags: bash, shell, chroot, jails, restricted-shell

As part of a script to set up a restricted user, I ran the `enable -n enable` command. For testing purposes I would like to undo that command but I can't find any documentation on how to do so. I know normally I would just run `enable enable`, but since that command is disabled that isn't an option.

The user in question is chrooted and running `rbash`, I have superuser access on the device and I have tried things like `sudo su -c "enable echo" usernameHere` with no success. I know I can always just scrap the user and start again, but I have a feeling that there's a better way that I'm missing, so I would like to avoid deleting the user if possible.

Any input and advice would be appreciated!

Comment: `enable` can't enable thing in rbash, anyway (it's restricted). Can you just run "bash" to open an unrestricted shell?

Comment: @NickMatteo yes I can, but the `enable` command is no longer found in that either